# Using mix of Unicode/Multibyte versions in libraries

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015

Here are 3 libraries with following `Character Set` support:
Lib **A** (Support Unicode and Multibyte)
Lib **B** (Only Multibyte)
Lib **C** (Only Unicode)

**A** has a function which is different in case of Unicode and Multibyte (example: `void func(string s)`) and it controlled in one of **A**'s header file as:

```
#if defined(UNICODE) || defined(_UNICODE)
#define string wstring
#endif
```

**B** uses **A**'s Multibyte version.
**C** uses **B**'s Multibyte version.

Now I am changing **C** which uses `void func(string s)` thru **B** defined above.
While compiling **C**, I get **linker error** for `func` as it looks for `wstring` version of function.

To solve this, I can create **Unicode** version of **B** as well which then I can use in **C**.

My question is, can this linker error be solved from changing something in **Lib A** itself so that I don't need to make **B**'s **Unicode** version?

Comment: It isn't quite clear what you mean by "Unicode" and why you contrast it to "multibyte". Unicode is a standard and a character set which features an *extremely* popular multibyte encoding. If you mean "wchar_t based strings" as opposed to "char based strings", say so (and mention your platform).

Comment: What compiler and platform is this for?  Are you able to rebuild B? Does it link with anything else except A? I would not bet on getting this to work correctly across compiler versions, but you might be lucky if B's linkage is purely based on exports of A and no other string functions are used.

Comment: I have just edited about Compiler. I am using VisualStudio 2015. @n.m., u are right, Unicode/multibyte I mean wchar_t and char based strings. @StartShine, everything builds and works fine unless I try to call `func` from **C**.

Comment: @n.m. I guess the confusion comes from how Microsoft describes it's use of UCS-2 in the Visual Studio IDE

Comment: @n.m. He is using Windows API which has "Multibyte" (`char`) and "Unicode" (`wchar_t`) versions of APIs. `wchar_t` based strings are UTF-16 encoded in this case.

Comment: Before you proceed deciding on the encoding which will be used in all libs, read this: http://utf8everywhere.org/ – opinionated article, but useful to bear in mind.

Comment: @ivanmoskalev Not very practical and also inefficient when working with the Windows API as you would constantly have to convert between UTF-8 and UTF-16.

Comment: @zett42 That's true (debugging std::string with UTF-8 characters in VS sucks), if you have only Windows and no portability concerns. If you have a codebase that must be portable between macOS and Windows and use wide-chars in your core, you are in the same trouble (converting on the API boundary) on macOS.

Comment: @ivanmoskalev Agreed, but it doesn't look as if OP has multiplatform concerns.

Comment: @zett42 Since it was not explicitly stated, the article might still be of use. Better to make an informed decision, knowledge is power, etc :)

Comment: `#define string wstring` is not a good idea. You might try `typedef basic_string<TCHAR> _tstring;`, and declare different functions names such as `fooA(char)` and `fooW(whcar_t)`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, so basically you are suggesting combining both versions together rather keeping separate libs for unicode and multibyte.

Comment: Well, I would recommend Unicode only version. You should clarify. I think you are just developing one library, you want your library to be compatible with both Unicode and ANSI? The ANSI version would be for other people who are too suborn to switch to Unicode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone (outside this forum) suggested me to add

```
#if defined(USE_MULTIBYTE) || defined(USE_UNICODE) 
#else 
#if defined(UNICODE) || defined(_UNICODE) 
#define USE_UNICODE 
#endif 
#endif 

#if defined(USE_UNICODE) 
typedef std::wstring xString; 
#else typedef std::string xString; 
#endif
```

in Lib A's header file.

Replace `string` to `xString` in all 3 libraries for relevant APIs.
`#define SM_USE_UNICODE` is Lib C's header file.

This way I don't need to make Unicode version of Lib B.
It actually allows Lib C to call multi-byte version of API.
**It looks hack as calling multi-byte API from unicode lib but it works.**

Answer (score -1):

If C accesses A via B, then if B does more than just ship a pointer between C and A, all three better agree on whether they work in Unicode (presumably 16-bit or larger code units) or in "multibyte" (8-bit code units).

Seems to me that your linker error is trying to prevent precisely this mismatch